# Virtual Host With SSL Support on OS X Mavericks

Tags: apache, ssl, https, virtualhost, osx-mavericks

I have a few virtual hosts setup on my local dev machine running Apache/2.2.24 on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).

My http-vhosts.conf file (that is configured to load through httpd.conf looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/testsite.com
   ServerName testsite.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/testsite2.com
   ServerName testsite2.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also configured my /etc/vhosts file to contain this line:

```
127.0.0.1       testsite2.dev
```

I want to be able to use the testsite2.dev over SSL (https).  I have tried multiple configurations of the vhosts config file with no luck.

With this current configuration, going to http://testsite2.dev pulls up the page I expect while https://testsite2.dev points to the apache home page at /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en

I have tried the following configuration, and multiple others, that do not work:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/testsite.com
   ServerName testsite.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/testsite2.com
   ServerName testsite2.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible to have a virtual host listen on port 80 and port 443 on a local machine?

Comment: Normally, you'd not use NameVirtualHost for SSL, you'd put each server on a different IP#, a'la `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>`, `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:443>` etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. I was simply missing a few directives to show where my certificate and key are located.  Here's what I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
   DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/testsite2.com"
   ServerName testsite2.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Shown in context, my http-vhosts.conf file looked like this:

```
Listen  *:443
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/testsite.com
   ServerName testsite.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
   DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/testsite2.com"
   ServerName testsite2.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't have a certificate and key installed, you can create your own by following a tutorial like this one:

http://www.cfdad.com/2012/12/12/creating-a-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-mac-osx-mountain-lion-apache/

It should work on both Mountain Lion and Mavericks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I guess you could have also enabled httpd-ssl.conf, but for a simple dev setup, this is nicely configured in one file.

Comment: I was also missing `Listen 443` in my httpd.conf